# Pulling out user details from Google Plus by email address

Tags: api, google-plus

I'm having trouble in pulling out user details from Google Plus account simply by searching for specific email address. I use https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search#try-it but when providing email address I always get empty result. Been searching for a while and after reading [google groups](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64) I think this is not possible at the moment.

Could someone clarify if this is the case or there is a way to pull out user photo simply by searching for specific email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not lookup Google+ profiles by email address. There is an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=64) that you can star, but please refrain from "+1" and "Me too!!1" comments.